# how to make user current user as parameter crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi, sapb1

i'm trying to develop a crystal report that can be used by 2 user (A&B) and this report shows value and qty. But, for user B only allowed to see qty.
How to make values seen as '***' or '###'?

Comment: Include what did you try and why didn't it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not that simple, as there's no "authorization" functionality built in to Crystal Reports.

One way you could implement it is through Formula fields, where if a persons is "authenticated" you show one value, otherwise you show another. You probably wouldn't want to hard-code the User codes, but you could use something like UDF in the User table to control permissions. You could also use Custom Authorizations but this is probably more work.

Let's assume you have a UDF in your User table called "Crystal Authorization (U_CRYSTAL_AUTH)" which is a True/False field and that you're bringing in the proper OUSR record into your report using the UserCode@ parameter token (this gives you the User Code of the current user), you could then create a formula in Crystal for each one of the fields you want to filter that looks like this (let's say this is the field to show Document Total):

```
if {OUSR.U_CRYSTAL_AUTH} = "T" then
   {OINV.DocTotal}
else
   "***"
```